# What `cut through' what?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, sentence, phrase-meaning

> Because deer feed at the edges of forests, these deer will be attracted to the spaces alongside the new roads being cut through Pataska Forest to serve the new residential areas.

In this sentence, what 'cut through' what?

I just wanted to change 'being cut through' to 'cutting through'.

Comment: The roads are being cut through the Pataska Forest?

Comment: 'being cut through' is not the same as 'cutting through'. -- P.S. "there deer" makes no sense to me.

Comment: They are cutting down forests to lay roads. Roads are "being cut" through the forest. HTH. The subject and object are pretty clear, only the semantics could be a bit confusing for some readers.

Comment: @michael.hor257k *There* = the place being talked about. The placing of *there* is a bit awkward indeed, though.

Comment: @Kris I know what *there* means, thank you. Still, *there deer* makes no sense to me in the given sentence.

Comment: @michael.hor257k As I said, the word is placed in an awkward location. Just read a comma after *there* - it is not a case of *there deer* as a phrase at all.

Comment: @Kris [shrug] ..

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sorry for typo, corrected.

Comment: @Kris Exactly, the subject and object are clear, but what does it mean by "Roads are 'being cut' through the forest?" The forest is cutting through the roads?

Comment: @LexintonAve They are cutting trees down in order to make room for new roads; roads that will lead through the (remaining) forest to the new residential areas. Lookup the definition of ***cut through***.

Comment: I understand that, but I mean that trees can be cut, but how can roads also be cut?

Comment: In the same way that a canal can be cut, and indeed some were named such as "new cut".

Comment: Roads can be cut through the forest because that's what you literally do. You cut a road through the forest. That is a very common expression, and even if you've not heard it before, it is very transparent and self-explanatory. I do not understand the question. This is a very simple sentence with only one possible meaning. I cannot fathom your comment above. When a knife cuts through butter, it does not mean that the butter cuts through the knife. Likewise, when a road is cut through the forest, it is the road that is being cut through the forest. That is what it *literally says*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I think they're confused because the passage "the new roads being cut through Pataska Forest" makes it sound like the road is being cut. The expression being used is "to cut something through something". The butter equivalent would be "The knife is cut through the butter." I'm not sure whether this sounds totally clear to someone unfamiliar. If this is so obvious maybe it belongs on ELL?

Answer (score 3):

"Cut through" is an idiom with several different senses.

In one sense it refers to routing -- one might "cut through" a church parking lot to get to a hard-to-reach restaurant, avoiding a busy intersection.  The same sense might be used with regard to a road -- the road "cuts through" the park rather than going around it.  In neither case is there any implication that something was physically cut.

At the other more literal extreme a surgeon will "cut through" the skin to remove a tumor.

In the OP's example, "cut through" is being used in a mix of these two senses.  The forest is being physically cut, and the road is being routed through the forest.

Changing "being cut through" to "cutting through" would lose the implication of being physically cut, and would make it unclear that the literal cutting action was ongoing.

(In other senses one might claim to "cut through the crap" in a political argument, and some emotional experience might "cut through to the heart" or some such.)

Comment: Related to this is "short cut."

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you don't usually "cut" a road unless you're clearing space for it or are doing earthworks or something of the sort.

If you see this article on [cut (earthmoving)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(earthmoving)), you can see that the first photo is captioned with "road cutting". You can see that the second photo is of a railway cut into granite. When something like this is done it's common to say the road is cut into/through whatever it passes through. The same can apply when clearing something that originally obstructs the passage of a road.

However since roads generally aren't "cut" when created in the way I mentioned above, it's most likely better to understand "cut through" as a phrasal verb instead of a "verb" and "preposition" separately, or possibly as the idiom "to cut [something] through [something]", where the thing actually being cut is the second [something], even though the first [something] seems to be the object of "cut":

> cut through
> 4. To create a passageway through something by cutting: 
> Someone had cut a path through the woods. 
> [The American Heritage Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+through)
>
> cut through
> phrasal verb
> cut through something
> 2.(also cut something through something) to make a path or passage through something by cutting 
> The prisoners cut their way through the barbed wire.
> [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cut-through)
>
> cut through (something)
> 5.To make a path through something. 
>  Our footprints cut a path through the freshly fallen snow.
>  [Farlex Dictionary of idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+through)

The most relevant part being "to cut [something] through [something]". So in:

> The prisoners cut their way through the barbed wire.

What is physically and literally being cut is the barbed wire, not "their way".

So imagine you're creating a pathway by laying down [stepping stones](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=stepping%20stones&FORM=HDRSC2), and your path is blocked by a crowd of people, a car, and a building. In order to create the pathway you need to disperse the crowd, move the car, and demolish the building. This would be "cutting a path through the obstacles". We say "cutting a path, but the path (the stones you lay down) aren't cut. In that sense, I understand why "cut through" is listed in a dictionary of idioms, because you're not actually cutting the path, ie., the stones. You're cutting through the obstacles in the way.